# typescript `this` is not what I expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I'm quite new to javascript/typescript. I have this code and I want to call a class function inside an event handler. The problem is that `this` is not what I expected.

```
class MyClass {

  private textInput: TextView;
  private _presenter: DateOptionPresenter;

  constructor(properties: { presenter: DateOptionPresenter } & CompositeProperties) {
    super(properties);
    this._presenter = properties.presenter;
    this.createUI();
  }

  private createUI() {
    this.append(
      this.textInput = new TextView({
        left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5
      }).on({tap: this.showDateDialog})
    );
  }

  private showDateDialog() {
    let selectedDate = new Date();
    new DateDialog({
      date: selectedDate
    }).on('select', (date) => this._presenter.fill(date))
    .open();
  }
}
```

So, In the last function showDateDialog(), when I call `this` it's in the TextView context instead of the MyClass, and `this._presenter` is undefined.

How can I access _presenter in there ?

Comment: please post the code line where `showDateDialog()` is called - maybe inside your template without using `.bind()` method?

Comment: `.on({tap: this.showDateDialog})` => `.on({tap: e => this.showDateDialog(e)})` See the linked question's answers for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just passing `this.showDateDialog` will lose the context to which the function was bound. You need either explicitly bind the context and return that or just call it inside another function.

```
.on({tap: () => this.showDateDialog()})
```

Comment: Why post ***yet another answer*** to this oft-duplicated question?

Comment: This is also not a good explanation. Context is vague. The function was indeed bound as you say, but it still is, just with the _exception_ of `this`.

Comment: Yep. that was the problem. Thanks. and sorry for the repost, I did not find answer before